# read the contents from pdf and neatly align the details

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

How to read the contents from pdf and neatly align the details in html page using php

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
print $contents;
```

But some unwanted symbols are coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to use [PDF2TEXT](http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a):

```
//Include here
include('class.pdf2text.php');

$var = new PDF2Text();

//Set PDF
$var->setFilename('YOUR PDF.pdf');
$var->decodePDF();

//Desired Output
echo $var->output();
```

Comment: Try to add as much detail as possible. Like URL of library you have suggested?

Comment: Kindly check this question if it solved your purpose. Thanks!

Comment: what changes are made to multiple pages and table containing pdf - Noman